# How to send an email using an API in python with an email that was received using POST method in html form?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an HTML form wherein when the user inputs their email, it'll immediately execute an email being sent to them. I'm doing this through a Mailgun API and a super simple HTML form, and whilst the form works and the code for sending the email works on its own as its own separate python file, I can't for the life of me figure out how the two can connect. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests
app = Flask("MyApp")

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template("emailform.html")
@app.route("/mail", methods=["POST"])
def sign_up():
    form_data = request.form
    print form_data["email"]
    return "Thanks"

def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxurl",
         auth=("api", "myapikey"),
         data={"from": "Excited User <mailgun@sandboxurl.mailgun.org>",
            "to": "email",
            "subject": "This is a subject line",
            "text": "This is the email body"})
send_simple_message()
app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `print` statement in `sign_up` with the code to send the message.

You'll probably need to `form_data` to fill out the email call, replacing the hard-coded strings you are using in `send_simple_message` with information from the form (I'd suggest passing the form as a parameter to `send_simple_message`).

Comment: Thank you! Could you clarify what you mean by needing to `form_data` to fill out the email call?